# copy list to another list in java with different memory positions

Tags: java

I want to copy a list to another list but they have to have different memory positions. I say this because I have this mistake and the code that I have is this.

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: toIndex = 223804
    at java.util.ArrayList.subListRangeCheck(ArrayList.java:1004)
    at java.util.ArrayList.subList(ArrayList.java:996)
    ...
```

I assign list to other but if I do changes in the copy, to the other, these changes affect.

A portion of the code

```
for (int i = 0; i < partsToCut; i++) {
                List<Segment> segmentListAux = new ArrayList<Segment>(tmx.getBody().getSegment());
                Tmx tmxAux = tmx;
                List<Segment> segmentList = null;
                if (i == partsToCut - 1) {
                    // Final case
                    segmentList = tmx
                            .getBody()
                            .getSegment()
                            .subList(contAnt, tmx.getBody().getSegment().size());
                } else {
                    segmentList = segmentListAux
                            .subList(contAnt, contPos);
                    contAnt += segments;
                    contPos += segments;
                }
                tmxAux.getBody().setSegment(segmentList);
                tmxList.add(tmx);
            }
```

In the second loop I get this mistake.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you update the code with some more description and show exact line where the exception occur.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to copy a list to another list but they have to have different
>   memory positions.

Why don't you just use a copy constructor? For example:

```
ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [`JavaDoc`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-):

Returns a view of the portion of this list between the specified fromIndex, inclusive, and toIndex, exclusive. (If fromIndex and toIndex are equal, the returned list is empty.) **The returned list is backed by this list, so non-structural changes in the returned list are reflected in this list, and vice-versa.** The returned list supports all of the optional list operations supported by this list.

Thus, this means that if you change anything from one list, the changes will be reflected in the other and vice versa.

Depending on how complex your `Segment` object is, you will need to do either a [`Shallow Copy`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Shallow_copy) such as by using the copy constructor of the list or else, you might need to do a [`Deep Copy`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_copy#Deep_copy), as shown [here](http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-deep-clone-example-source-code).